# Prevent SharePoint list item deletion

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

How can I prevent users from deleting sharepoint task list item?
Should i override the ItemDeleting event or is there any other site level options available to achieve the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could also set up a custom permission level out of the box.

1. Navigate to your Site Collection (if you're in a subsite, you can go to Site Actions -> Site Settings ->  Go to top level site settings)
2. Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Advanced permissions
3. Click Settings -> Permission Levels
4. Click Add a permission level

I would recommend using the existing "Contribute" permission level as a guide and just uncheck the "Delete Items" list permission. Then, you can give your users that permission to the list.

Comment: Agreed with this approach.  I've done this and called the permission level something like "Contribute without Delete"

Answer (score 10):

You can use List Item Event Receiver, ItemDeleting method:

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.ErrorMessage = "User don't have permission";
    properties.Cancel = true;
}
```